How do you gloss "personal a" in Spanish?
The Spanish preposition "a" is used in transitive sentences when the object is definite and animate, for example in
Veo     a mi hermana 
see.1sg ? my sister 
"I see my sister"

How does one gloss the preposition in this usage? I couldn't find any examples.

I don’t recall ever seeing this in glossing, but perhaps something like ‘OBJ.PREP’ or ‘OBJ.ANIM’ could work?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

the following comment was incorrectly moved to chat (as it was unrealted to the chat and addresses the asker). It's important to note that personal a doesn't apply to definite and animate objects, it applies to personal objects, whether definite or not. Definiteness can be seen to not be relevant with examples like "matar a un hombre" or "ver a alguien" which both have indefinite objects. It can also be seen to be specifically personal objects rather than merely animate ones by examples like "mira la vaca" with an animate but not personal direct object which does not receive personal a

@Tristan You might want to check out the RAE: LA PREPOSICIÓN A EN EL COMPLEMENTO DIRECTO Como regla general, el complemento directo lleva la preposición a cuando hace referencia a personas u otros seres animados, y no suele llevarla cuando designa cosas. There are exceptions. So, ver a alguien would be: veo a mi hermana //What is a personal direct object? We'd say: direct object that is a person

@Lambie that doesn't disagree with what I said about it being for personal objects, not definite animate ones...

@Tristan This  "It's important to note that personal a doesn't apply to definite and animate objects, it applies to personal objects, whether definite or not." It applies to persons and other animate beings. Translation by me from the Real Academia Española.

ah, yes, it does apply to some non-people, but not to non-personal objects. It depends on the degree of anthropomorphism. It's normal to use personal a with pets (which are conceived of as personal, see also the way English often uses he/she/they to refer to pets much moreso than it does other animals), but not most other animals. Compare the n-grams for mira un gato vs mira a un gato vs mira una vaca vs mira a una vaca. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mira+una+vaca%2Cmira+a+una+vaca&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=es&smoothing=3

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mira+un+gato%2Cmira+a+un+gato&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=es&smoothing=3

@Tristan It means little out of context....ngrams, we don't know the context. You keep saying: personal objects and non-personal objects. A personal object for me is what I have in my handbag.

Ok, so now the OP has an answer, done by an academic, found by me and posted in my revamped answer. It would be real nice if people removed some of those dv's. And this: Want to improve this answer? Add details and include citations to explain why this answer is correct. Answers without enough detail may be edited or deleted. should be followed by those who previously dv'ed me. Thank you go Janus Bahs Jaquet and Tristan for explaining the question to me.

Spanish personal a is an example of differential object marking, so we can compare how other differential object markers are glossed.
The Wikipedia page for differential object marking includes glossed examples from Sakha:

кини яблоко-ну  сии-р-∅

kini yabloko-nu sii-r-∅

NOM  apple-ACC  eat

'She/he is eating the/a (particular) apple.'


vs

кини яблоко  сии-р-∅

kini yabloko sii-r-∅

NOM  apple   eat

'She/he is eating some apple or other.'


Here the marker is glossed as ACC, with the fact that it's a differential object marker (and so would be absent on many other direct objects) not being explicitly noted.
Lambie's answer links to  Camacho Ramírez's 2022 paper Differential Object Marking and Labeling in Spanish (available here) which includes several glossed examples of personal a. As the paper is primarily concerned with the precise conditions around personal a, many of the examples are somewhat overcomplicated for the purposes of an answer here, however gloss 29a is illustrative:

Juan vio      a   una actriz,  a   María

Juan see-PAST ACC an  actress, ACC Mary [sic]

'John saw an actress, Mary'


As in the example of differential object marking in Sakha, we can see that personal a is glossed as ACC.

This does not answer the question. It is only a cut-and-paste from a Wikipedia page.

@Lambie the question askes how to gloss personal a, and I give a possibility, highlighting how similar features are glossed in other languages. You can disagree with my answer, but to claim it is only a cut-and-paste from wikipedia is objectively wrong

I found  the paper, edited my answer and now you post from the same paper? And your example contains an appositive which the question does not contain and which my example from the paper doesn't contain either.

imo the parentheses in the examples you quote (because the paper's concerned with grammaticality judgements) make it less clear than this example with the appositive. As for the fact I used the same paper as you, I do make explicit that I got it from your answer. I would also not have done this if I thought the only substantial difference between our answers was your reference to this paper. As it is, I stand by the position that my answer is better-formatted and more precisely targetted at the question, and so it is appropriate for me to use the reference

Well, frankly, I'd call it filching. Also, my example is exactly the same structure as in the OP's question. My answer was ok for the word-to-word interlinear but only after I redid it did it become OK for the morpheme one. As for better formatted, I don't think that necessarily a good answer makes. Also, I explain about personal a which is an English term re Spanish teaching. I just used the layout in the paper. No reason not to.

"personal a" is an English term used in teaching Spanish.
In Spanish, they (the Real Academia Espanhola) explain it this way, under the uses of the preposition a:

LA PREPOSICIÓN A EN EL COMPLEMENTO DIRECTO
Como regla general, el complemento directo lleva la preposición a
cuando hace referencia a personas u otros seres animados, y no suele
llevarla cuando designa cosas. Existen, sin embargo, numerosas
excepciones, así como algunas alternancias y ciertos casos dudosos:
• Llevan siempre la preposición a los nombres propios de personas y
animales:
Ayer vi a Manuela; Tienes que sacar a Canelo.


• Los nombres comunes de personas y animales llevan preposición cuando van precedidos del artículo u otros determinantes que los identifiquen:
Ayer vi a mi amiga; Tienes que sacar al perro.


• No la llevan cuando no son identificables, bien por ir sin determinante, bien por ir precedidos de un u otros indefinidos:


La universidad debe formar investigadores; Causaron muchos heridos.


Con un/una se dan numerosas alternancias. Obsérvese la diferencia entre Busca (una) traductora (‘alguna, la que sea’) y Busca a una traductora (‘una en particular’).

Here is the answer to the question:


Conditions on DOM in Spanish

In Spanish, the differential object marking (DOM) seems to respond to
two general conditions: certain characteristics of the object, and
certain properties of the verb.2 Consider the following sentences3:

The grammaticality of (1a) shows that a preposition A is mandatory
with animate objects, and the impossibility of (1b) shows that the
mark is not possible with inanimate objects. Thus, it is possible to
establish the following first condition in relation to the Spanish
DOM: The Animacy Condition: Direct objects can be marked with A if
they are animates. In the literature, the participation of animacy in
the DOM of Spanish is widely accepted (Torrego (1998); Aissen (2003);
Rodríguez-Mondoñedo (2007); López (2012); Bleam (2005); Von Heusinger
and Kaiser (2011); and Brugè and Brugger (1996), among others. For an
analysis of the animacy feature in the syntax of Romance languages,
see Cyrino (2018)). However, there are some cases where direct
inanimate objects can be marked with A:

In this article, the topic of DOM in inanimate objects will not be
developed; however, I would like to sketch some hypotheses about (2).4
In cases such as (2a), the inanimate object would have been animated.
In (2b), the morpheme A would not be a DOM mark; these are verbs that
always govern the preposition A (see Camacho Ramirez 2019).5 In (2c),
the DOM mark would be DOM, and would express plural. Cases such as
(2c) are restricted to verbs that have a feature [quantize] in the
verb, according to Rodríguez-Mondoñedo (2007). Therefore, we can say
that the presence of A with inanimate objects (2) does not override
the proposed Animacy Condition. [and the article continues]
Differential Object Marking and Labeling in Spanish

Open AccessArticle
Differential Object Marking and Labeling in Spanish
by Rafael Camacho RamírezORCID
Linguistic Department, Universidade de São Paulo, São Paulo 05508-070, Brazil
Languages 2022, 7(2), 114; https://doi.org/10.3390/languages7020114
Submission received: 28 December 2021 / Revised: 18 March 2022 / Accepted: 23 March 2022 / Published: 6 May 2022
(This article belongs to the Special Issue Exploring the Syntax-Semantics Interface in the Romance Languages)
The first image functions just like the OP's question.

This does not address the question. The question is about how to gloss personal a, not how to use it, or why it should be used. It also misunderstands how it is used. It is not that certain verbs require certain prepositions when directed at people. It is that whenever a direct object is personal, it must always be preceded by the preposition a. It is always that preposition that is needed, and it is all verbs that take direct objects

you may also want to actually look up what gloss means in linguistics. It is not an explanation of something. I'd have thought the question would also have made that clear: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlinear_gloss

To gloss means to explain. It is explained by showing that the verb takes a. The OP states: How does one gloss the preposition in this usage? That is what I have done. I have parsed its usage. Sure, in translation. OK

To gloss does not mean to explain in this context. It means to provide a linguistic gloss next to or below a quoted word, consisting of a translation of the root/base word plus various morphosyntactic information about the specific form quoted, and most commonly formatted according to the Leipzig Glossing Rules.

@JanusBahsJacquet No, that is your gloss of the question, not mine. In any event, I have explained how it works. I think you are overeading this. To say I don't address the question is simply outrageous. I know what a gloss is, in translation. A literal word-for-word is what it is. I doubt the OP knows what the Leipzig Glossing rules are and I did a word for word in my answer.

@Lambie the asker literally gives an interlinear gloss (admittedly without the alignment, but that's tricky to implement on stackexchange, which is why I also omitted it in my answer) in their question, it's clear that's what they're referring to. As I've thought many times before, your profile on ELL says, "few people know how to listen to others", and seemingly you are not one of those few given your frequent catastrophic misunderstandings you obstinately refuse to recognise

sure, it doesn't get the Leipzig rules quite right, but it is still an interlinear gloss, and it's clear that that is what is intended. I can just about understand not picking that up when you read the question, but continuing to insist that it isn't the obvious intent of the asker is absurd

also, your glosses are also not aligned properly either

@Tristan says "alignment, but that's tricky to implement on stackexchange" — The current change to monospaced font does the trick (but possibly causes horizontal scrolling). Using a markdown table usually looks better (but takes longer to enter).

@Lambie your glosses are not aligned by words, and your final gloss for the Spanish is some weird frankenstein on one line that leaves PREP and OBJ just randomly floating rather than attached to any segment. Additionally, PREP is not included in the Leipzig glossing rules as a standard abbreviation

Who says only Leipzip is valid? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations See: PREP for preposition. I don't know how to format but that's the answer. And PREP at https://academic.oup.com/edited-volume/38630/chapter/335270756 The Oxford Book of Linguistic Typology The abbreviations used in this handbook are based largely on the Leipzig Glossing Rules Also here: https://brill.com/display/book/9789004448766/front-8.xml?language=en

@Lambie you're the one who was putting the Leipzig rules forward as the source of truth, and said that "a is PREP, according to Leipzig" (which is false). I haven't voted to delete this answer, and it is absolutely a correct answer now that it has the second section, although it could do with further editing; the first section is irrelevant, and the second is entirely a quote with no commentary

that paper on the actual use of personal a is extremely interesting though!

@Tristan OK, let's just stop, OK? The OP now has their answer so a -8 might just be a record on an answer that is correct. And read this academic paper from the third link above in my comments that shows the PREP is in the rules: Abbreviations for Linguistic Glosses and Terms
The following abbreviations adhere to the Leipzig Glossing Rules, with the exception of MAT and PAT.

My downvote was added before this answered the question. As it now does so I have retracted that vote

@Tristan Thanks.  Let's see if others retract. Also, the Leipzig rules was not me initially. It was JBJ addressing me, he mentioned it.
